# How do I reference programmatically generated $scope variables in my template?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array fetched from the server from which I generate a variable number of boolean flags and attach them to my `$scope` variable in my controller.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    $scope['TeamId' + myArray[i].TeamId + 'IsVisible'] = ViewMatrixService['TeamId' + myArray[i].TeamId + 'IsVisible'];
}
```

How do I reference these variables in my template? I tried the below, but it doesn't work.

```
<th ng-show="'TeamId' + doc.DocumentOwnerTeam.TeamId + 'IsVisible'">
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are showing a string in your html. The part doc.DocumentOwnerTeam.TeamId may not have been evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put them in a scope variable that you can explicitly reference.

```
$scope.team = $scope.team || {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    $scope.team['TeamId' + myArray[i].TeamId + 'IsVisible'] = ViewMatrixService['TeamId' + myArray[i].TeamId + 'IsVisible'];
}
```

`<th ng-show="team['TeamId' + doc.DocumentOwnerTeam.TeamId + 'IsVisible']">`

Though as an alternate route, if it's always going to be determined by whatever iteration of `doc.DocumentOwnerTeam` is currently active, just assign it as a property to *that*.